# How to call https api from wpf

Tags: wpf, api, https

I'm trying to call the https API from the WPF application but i'm getting this error:

> InnerException = {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
>   error occurred on a send."} Message = "An error occurred while sending
>   the request."

Can anyone help me what exactly the problem is?

```
  private static readonly string apiURL = 
                "https://api.totalsynergy.com/api/v2/Profile/Index";    

  private async Task<bool> GetAuth(string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage hpm = await hc.GetAsync(apiURL);

            if (hpm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var res = await hpm.Content.ReadAsAsync<Organization>();
            }

            return boolValue;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            return boolValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When is HTTPS, connection requires some protocols.
In my example I have a API URL that I call and can send some information and receive the response in JSON. You can adapt this to your problem:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

               //get OS version
                var query = "SELECT version FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";
                var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
                var info = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
                string version = info.Properties["Version"].Value.ToString();
                int majorVersion = Int32.Parse(version.Substring(0, version.IndexOf(".")));

                //OS version is windows xp or older
                if (majorVersion < 6)
                {
                    //tls 1.0
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192;
                }
                else
                {
                    //tls 1.1 or tls 1.2
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
                }

                //url to send data
                string url = **YOUR URL**


                //create request
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Timeout = 240000;
                request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                request.Method = **REQUEST METHOd GET/POST**;

                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";

                //convert to byte stream
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(**Text to send  or empty**);


                //specify content of request - this example is in JSON
                request.ContentType = "application/json";

                if (requestMethod != RequestMethods.GET)
                {

                    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

                    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

                    //send
                    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

                    requestStream.Close();
                }

                try
                {

                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    string result;
                    using (var readers = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        return result = readers.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    return null;

                }
                finally
                {
                    request.Abort();
                }
```